# Add property without naming existing properties by Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

In `Linq` how we can add new properties besides other existing properties without mention them.

For example we have the class `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass
{
   public int P1 {get; set;}
   public int P2 {get; set;}
}
```

and at runtime:

```
List<MyClass> list = // some MyClass objects as List ...
```

and the wrapperlist which has three more new properties

```
var wrapperlist = list.Select(m=>
new
{
  P1 = m.P1  // I don't want to do this
  P2 = m.P2  // I don't want to do this
  NewP1 = someNewVal1
  NewP2 = someNewVal2
  NewP3 = someNewVal3
});
```

**Notice** that i don't like using new Wrapper class for new properties which is subclass of `MyClass` and it get the `MyClass` object as constructor argument or some thing like this, **Because** the wrapper class is a general class and it has its fixed properties (`NewP1` ,`NewP2` ,`NewP3`) and it is designed to wrap any kind of objects (for example `MyClass`). so any kind of solutions that causes we have modifications in `MyClass` definition is unacceptable.

**Update:**
The `Wrapper` class is an anonymous object which has been created at runtime inside the `Select` extension method.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What "Wrapper class" are you talking about? I see no Wrapper class here.

Comment: You are creating an anonymous type (with the new { }), .NET classes' structure can not be modified at run-time.

Comment: i updated the post, please say me if it's not clear. Thank you for attentions.

Comment: Maybe you should try to use dictionary or dynmic objects? `var wrapperlist = list.Select(m=>
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
  {"P1", m.P1},
  {"P2", m.P2},
  {"NewP1", someNewVal1},
  {"NewP2", someNewVal2},
  {"NewP3", someNewVal3}
});`

Comment: There is no way to do this automatically safely. What if you add a `NewP1` property to your `MyClass`? (If you say "but I won't do that" -- I can't know that, the compiler can't know that, the runtime can't know that.)

Comment: actually i have to make a service that gets any kind of object and adds some members to it and returns. in here the wrapper class is my return type. I like this way because there no need to modify objects definitions and everything happens at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you?

```
var wrapperlist = list.Select(m =>
new
{
    WrappedObject = m,
    NewP1 = someNewVal1,
    NewP2 = someNewVal2,
    NewP3 = someNewVal3
});
```

Comment: This is good idea and i voted up your answer, but unfortunately this is not what i want. please consider that i want to make members of the WrappedObject (m) , in beside of the other members (NewP1, ...).